# Change Array contents to correct for NULL api returns

Tags: php

First, the code:

```
for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
$rgames[$j] = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            array_push($rgames[$j], array($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled, $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths));
    }};
```

json[0] through [4] contains 5 arrays, which contains 10 more for the data of each player's past 10 games. From the code above, everything is pulled out and organized properly, which one small problem. The API I'm using only returns non-empty values in the interest of bandwidth, so I'm stuck with some NULLs here and there. I need to find those and change them to zeros, so I have something proper to display, and so my error log will stop whining at me.

I hope I've provided enough information. I've only learned PHP about 2 weeks ago, so I'm still trying to get the hang of it. Thanks for any information!

EDIT: Final code in an answer below.

Comment: post the print_r of the array

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I wasn't sure which one you wanted, so here's the print_r of $json: http://pastebin.com/7eFc5sdE  and here's the one of $rgames: http://pastebin.com/MLmvcSCp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `$json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled` and `$json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths` are the variables that are sometimes coming up null? If so you can check for null and set 0.

```
/* shorthand if/else in array */
array_push($rgames[$j], array(
    (isset($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled)) ? $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled : 0, 
    (isset($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths)) ? $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths : 0
));
```

Alternatively, if the variables should be integers, you can use intval to convert them to integers. If they already are integers, nothing changes. If they are null or empty, they become 0.

```
array_push($rgames[$j], array(
    intval($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled), 
    intval($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths)
));
```

Comment: Everything pulled from the API is an integer, so I used your intval method and it worked great! The only thing is that PHP still complains about it in my error logs (Undefined property: stdClass::$championsKilled, etc. etc. for the other ones, too). Do you think I should just @ them and shut them up?

Comment: Best practice is to avoid using @ and check for the variables with `isset()`. I'll update the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After changing a bit of @Samutz's code, I was able to come up with this final code:

```
for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
$rgames[$j] = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            array_push($rgames[$j], array(isset($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled) ? $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->championsKilled : 0, isset($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths) ? $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->numDeaths : 0, isset($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->assists) ? $json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->assists : 0, empty($json[$j]->games[$i]->stats->win) ? "Loss" : "Win"));
}};
```

Thanks all!